# How to render asp image tags in masterpage/page layout?

Tags: html, asp.net, sharepoint

In my .html page layout file, I have this code

```
<!--<asp:Image runat="server" imageurl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/en-us/help.gif %>" alternatetext="More information" />-->
```

And then in the rendered client side result, if I view the source of the page, it looks like

```
<!--<img src="/Style%20Library/en-us/help.gif" alt="More information" />-->
```

and the comments prevent it from being parsed into an image. How can I fix this?

Note: for SP2013 html files for pages, I need the comments around controls like asp or sharepoint controls.

Thanks

Comment: if it is a static image why not just use html tag? If I am reading this correctly, doing that you would not need to comment out that line and all should work fine.

Comment: I want to use the same src, how should I make it look like?